# Difference between New page, New entry and New Showcase

Tags: bolt-cms

I have been testing bolt-cms for a few days and I'm trying to understand how it works.

I want to know what is the difference between New page, New entry and New Showcase.

I have read [this](https://docs.bolt.cm/contenttypes-and-records) and it didn't fill the gap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pages, Entries and Showcases are just examples of different Contenttypes and can all be replaced with what ever you like.

Pages are an example to emulate what you might need/want for standard site pages.

Entries an example of something like a blog post.

Showcases are an example of a useless Contenttype that gives an example of how you might use most of the available field types.